# There is a Windows 10 lock screen wallpaper that really caught my attention. Does anyone know the location of this picture?

Tags: where-on-earth, montenegro, lock-screens

[image]

The information given by Windows 10 is that this picture was taken somewhere in Montenegro. Can someone please give the exact location?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A quick Google Search for "Windows 10 Montengro" gave this link

http://www.where-is-this.com/index/view/5546.html

Described as: **Montenegro, Durmitor mountain range, Durmitor Hotel**

Comment: My daily vote limit has been reached, I'll get to this tomorrow, well done

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately when I type this search into google (.at) I don't get any helpful results on the first few pages. But your information is correct, the location is here: https://goo.gl/maps/G2Up2j364wt

Answer (score 4):

Clicking on any of the text elements takes you to a Microsoft Edge search page of images for the location on any of the lockscreens.

Comment: Usually this is true, but unfortunately in this particular case thelocation given by Windows 10 is "Montenegro" only.