# Where was this night time photograph taken (Windows 10 lock screen image)?

Tags: where-on-earth, lock-screens

This picture was on my Windows 10 lock screen and I can't find any information.

[image]

Comment: Related - http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83234/there-is-a-windows-10-lock-screen-wallpaper-that-really-caught-my-attention-doe/83236#83236

Comment: http://techdows.com/2016/01/where-windows-10-themes-photos-were-taken.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZittDRhUkSEAsrvtGLwlKJddMHJsejEmtn9A_1VYxocUO1honl7Cg81zI8wJfMcwOEhiIlO0A3uR_1rP5ntlnXJ2o1S3WOqWqFmI6cKAWPMB2LXdYBlJeu9bW2p6ykw_16rUivie8DNRf6NFn3ywNQrkV8x3SSNQnrtQ4QHiIBA6JP39_1JHRyyAqEB7Mf46VMubBMMvmDg2uk-QRzsUvCPkHxg1YAXqJnGH4LF_1uhzKrXSGeXLVj2wf4veFQ8sKtfQt1mriy-jL75onMioRNTgte-BBDlP0xjXymyMBNHp2NOREf63fIZ0efHrDu-Hgr4gjWyhmetbnXZKTqBy5QBYvqwpvDIyWACRkFzUJISk8X04SYUEGxEgLDgsxAp45FZdq2RRl-6nAU6WvkpwFUTVdnm4T0kiRRzEQBDNRvj9XASefh0b3t9WjygiWt4ND25kpPfLoTaYmnSEPf1vSe5bWB7RQmIwsymPVtBWmq8vreoy4_18263p8SRka_17G87m77YKDwpTcdnmC_1Yr0VwhU0RpM2XdB7acz1kwUT9pBMsHCnPEjtl2-FbXQrFftIEOTLBk7Nw1RdJwKbZmvp-4JLxW2ja1FjLPb2hOmHFzOLPEaN3SFINa7r_1nFxsQGt6voZozepkgAv9wVQE35AFgbPJU9gOqev-wGjv8PSWWq3rIyDwQ9rDjBSdH_1JLnfZyqppjS-j9sXT6YP17MQvpeM4_1Q9jigMMORVokpLwX4pM7imQjM4PXppEqRNxqyDeq1kB1YNySXiaPGXVvwdYKGT2HJCMQ4672XUtVWh65nhgRbtyzzYJfMrBEmn0cgDSfFQ8lrBgwUpt-Ob-VtSThVlm5buNLMHo_1l03mbS47CQs9EConSbEBrH4hQ9o6r5Iy4xoSqsmE1iIQP8TK3d5vMwabknnx9BYdwUbJpIeSTKl0MjUK-YkwReZdRijdZczjrTvkjU7W_1FQE4FBL9RS7rnXrdqxdNjOmYsF_1hRW6AZAeOtIVVKpAVx3l-Db8qbqOgbz5ZEreNVYcWmDJhveel4i7R89fjv_1Xx9bzugK9HYOs541XB22JAoCg4aCgNOqeIAleWUyguHjrKZzlPP7qCMD2wdQFudlXup4-TKJ2y3OBbFVk34JJUwjiqEeTVsBgWR3pbmL7RRrac0w-OIJaoEsDq-uP2UkMo3D3TFc1WkG5S8vztv6tkpSXN8vnWyPWRglwJHMzCsUS9TCIbww9_186FTEqtC7MCdIzMgF_1bMBmtXODR4-9FgontIKVQEB2_1wdQpMq2N9UBoPdB7Jv1Zgr0Qkz99xN1ZQh_1ScEToOokktTTBMuXBw0aIkvz1Dxy1nRHzoiTxGs8LlKbwl8_155ENCSaPew1UL1sg8C-5Bm81ln8ZmCy6SvCG7jimmx10O0vgCpJQVEJK_1NID0t41-CuEfAIj-Qt7B1AvQbHXHbd28wiq4na-KNxEpE7gUUQeHUK_1JS5E8tJdGYhJMY10jJPUFg5LO83uVqhffK0Vubus6SU-PPZ3-LbgAb5Bbt71Wiokm0EF8ceQ4mewRQLRnQo98Nt0Kp4ZGc4JBwsb3z2E6BaNppzLdr3ltNISk9_1QA38rhPOSlh5aEcg4QWvPEZ93HqW-htjqkKuazXu2G_1ca7akLMwre9Tos5N2VIM-dQzNrld9QxmMKrDbu-xQEPQQIAIN-yYdpTlAcQDTpRF45jw-yRb14DtbWatvkw2oK5I2KGyGpoZgckWDnR-XWFTfchLrc1LfEXlFxk91aNt_1bvo4nZo2paJyU&hl=en) this is Philispburg, San Marteen at night. During the day it looks like this:

[image]
*Image courtesy of [DreamsTime](https://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-images-philispburg-sint-maarten-dutch-antilles-philipsburg-maaren-nighttime-townscape-great-salt-pond-image36645849)*

Answer (score 2):

google (which is your friend when asking this kind of question) says that is it Philispburg, Sint Maarten by night .

Link to google map:

https://goo.gl/maps/e7GwFhVz1mE2

Comment: And now google brings you here